# Unable to restore backup taken on one server onto another server

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2014

I am using **SQL Server 2014 version 12.0.2000.8** on both systems. When I try to restore the backup taken from the first system onto the second system it says:

> No backup set selected to be restored

However I can restore it on the first system without any errors. I also tried to restore using the following command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE EBS_ATM 
FROM DISK = 'G:\ebsBkup\ebs_bkup.bak'
```

The above command threw the following error message:

> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I have checked rights and permissions on the folder as well as the `.bak` file.

Database version was checked through the query `DetermineVersionOfSQLServer.sql` in the Microsoft Knowledge Base article, [How to determine the version, edition and update level of SQL Server and its components](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/321185).

- The database does not already exist on the second instance
- `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` and `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` also throw error 3103
- I know there should be another message before the 3013 eror, but I am getting only the messages I have posted.

The bak file is quite big ~70 GB. First I 7zipped and copy-pasted. Didn't work. Then I 7Zipped in 700 MB tranches. Didn't work. Finally I copied without zipping. Didnt work.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You could maybe check for NTFS File permissions... Otherwise, according to [a post on sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1679869-3411-1.aspx) you should update to at least CU5.

Comment: Have you tried to take another backup? Make sure you do it `WITH INIT` so that there is no confusion about which backup file to use. You probably need to use `WITH MOVE` on the restore as well, unless the data/log paths match exactly on both systems.

Comment: @Jefferson I will look into the NTFS permission part tomorrow. As for CU5  I believe it is needed if the versions are different. Both systems in my case have exact same version.

Comment: @Aaron I will try the WITH INIT suggestion tomorrow. I have already tried WITH MOVE and it gave same error. I have also scrapped the backup and took a fresh one. Lets hope it works. Thanks for the help,

Comment: `WITH INIT` is for the backup, not the restore.

Comment: Ah yes. Will take fresh backup with init then. Cheers.

Comment: Does the RESTORE FILELIST work from the original server with the original copy of the database?

Comment: Just 1 more point to consider:  I'd copy the backup file *back* to the original server, unzip, and attempt to restore that specific file.  Perhaps something happens during the transportation and/or uncompression process that isn't caught when it's restored on the source? Worst case, you could also check a 3rd server and get 'quorum' :)

Comment: @Kenneth Yes RESTORE FILELIST works on original server with the same backup. RESTORE DATABASE also works. I have taken a fresh backup with WITH INIT as suggested by Aaron. Will try to see if it works.

Comment: So I took backup with WITH INIT as suggested by Aaron and tried to restore but came across same error. Then I tried Ali' process of copying the .bak back to first server and restoring. That worked perfectly so the issue is not .bak corruption. And I still putter along in hope of a solution...

Comment: I presume you used replace WITH MOVE? WITH replace, Move etc

Comment: Are there any errors in the event viewer that may point to more hints?

Answer (score 2):

> No backup set selected to be restored

As SqlBak Blog  [Here](https://sqlbak.com/blog/no-backupset-selected-to-be-restored/) the above error comes in two scenario.

> 1)You are trying to restore your database to a lower version of SQL
>   Server. If you make a database backup on a higher version, let’s say
>   SQL Server 2012 and then you try to restore it on SQL Server 2004, you
>   will get this error message: No Backupset Selected to be Restored.
>
> 2)The backup file is unreadable or corrupted. You can simply check
>   your database backup using the following command:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='D:/DatabaseBackupFileName.bak';
```

I think as my knowledge it's a incomplete error message.  Because most of the time along with Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3, the operating system errors  (like Operating system Error 3,5 etc) or some  error come.

> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

For this error i would recommend to `Pinal Dave blog` [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/sql-server-fix-error-msg-3159-level-16-state-1-line-1-msg-3013-level-16-state-1-line-1/),[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/12/08/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-5access-is-denied/) and MSDN Blog [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2487231)

Even  `Remus Rusanu` answer also in dbastackstange related to Network drive with same error message [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/sql-server-2008-database-restore-error-cannot-open-backup-device-15105)

Answer (score 0):

If TDE is enabled you will need to either move the certificate or asymmetric key that is used to open the database encryption key or decrypt the database take a backup to a new file then move and restore on the new server. [Microsoft link: Move a TDE Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff773063(v=sql.120).aspx)